# Scale up background image grid of thumbnails to higher res in html css only

Tags: css, background, hover, image

Hi I am using 'background image' to make a simple grid (2x3) of thumbnails that will either be landscape or portrait this works well. But I want them to scale up to higher res images on hover. I assume the higher res ones need to be hidden in some way.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the `background-size:` property from CSS3:

Simple HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <span class="clear"></span>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}

.thumb
{
    background: url(http://placehold.it/100x100) no-repeat;
    background-size: 50% 50%; /*CSS3*/
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    -webkit-transition: background-size 1s; /*CSS3*/
    -moz-transition: background-size 1s; /*CSS3*/
}

.thumb:hover
{
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-transition: background-size 1s; /*CSS3*/
    -moz-transition: background-size 1s; /*CSS3*/
    cursor: pointer; 
}

span.clear
{
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}
​
```

What you do is serve up the higher res images straight away, and then scale them down using the `background-size:` property. Then on hover you scale up the image. This prevents loading two versions of each image and with the CSS3 transitions it can look pretty cool too ;)

Remember that this is CSS3 so (I think) IE8 and lower won't support this.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/CFM5Q/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a modification of Kyle's answer. I'm not sure it will suit your needs (doesn't use `background-image`, but rather just an `<img>` tag), but I'm posting it just in case anyone finds it useful. Instead of using background-sizing, it's also possible to use CSS3 transforms (`scale` in this case) and transitions.

http://jsfiddle.net/vheVk/1/

Comment: This is also good for a gallery as the <img> tag makes the images relevant to the content. So Google and other bots can see that the images are relevant to the site, whereas using bg images cancels this out. +1